# Draw an outline of form with graphics

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing

Basically I have a form with no border, I want to keep it like that. It's in a fixed position. I'm trying to draw an outline of the form size in the form (so it looks like a border) I'm having trouble and never really used "drawing" techniques in forms.

```
Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 20);
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);
Graphics g = CreateGraphics();
g.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
```

Comment: So did that code not work when you tried it? Did you get an error message?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it in `OnPaint`:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
    base.OnPaint(e);
    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 20);
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
}
```